# EF Core search with operator in the query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am looking to accomplish something like the following but in a net core project:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/performing-searches.html

The end result would be an API endpoint that accepts a field, value, and a condition type. something like:

```
www.site.com/post?field=animal&value=dog&condition=like&field=age&value=3&condition=gt
```

I have not found any examples of this being done with ef core. I could possibly write my own service that could accomplish this but I am hoping to find an example or nuget package that already does this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe OData is what you want: https://www.odata.org/ https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/ https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/odata/

Comment: OData solved my problem.